# Python Selenium button click for cookies

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

Issue is with accepting cookies, I'm not sure why nothing works, tried `By.CLASS, By.NAME` etc. to accept cookies `"Sutinku su visais"` must be chosen

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = Service("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=PATH)

driver.get("https://www.telia.lt/privatiems")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-primary js-cookie-modal-accept")
link.click()
```

Doesnt matter how long I put pause/wait, all the time same issue:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to 
 locate element
```

Highly appreciated if anyone can educate me on how to locate in HTML the buttons I want by different criterias, as from what I tried already could not achieve anything.

HTML in which I'm trying to accept cookies:

```
<div class="button-group button-group--pull-left" data-gtm-vis-has-fired-2746359_1882="1">
                <input class="btn btn-primary js-cookie-modal-accept" type="submit" value="Sutinku su visais" data-gtm-vis-has-fired-2746359_1882="1">
                <a class="btn btn-link js-cookie-modal-settings" data-gtm-vis-has-fired-2746359_1882="1">
                    Slapukų nustatymai
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class name does not have support for spaces or multiple spaces in Selenium `CLASS_NAME`

Please covert this

```
btn btn-primary js-cookie-modal-accept
```

into a `CSS selcetor` by putting `.` and removing spaces.

```
.btn.btn-primary.js-cookie-modal-accept
```

So your effective code block would be :

```
link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOTR, ".btn.btn-primary.js-cookie-modal-accept")
link.click()
```

As requested by OP, this is one way to check the HTML DOM

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

I would also recommend you to use ExplicitWait driven by WebDriverWait

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-primary.js-cookie-modal-accept"))).click()
except:
    print("Could not click")
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: well that did the trick, probably need to look up documentation for further info.

Comment: Yup, see above for best practices.